# asp.net core with Azure authentification and azure load balancer

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-load-balancer

I'm working on a Asp.Net Core MVC Site with a normal Azure Active Directory authentification. The authentification works great in our normal envoirments but now we want put the WebApp into azure high availibility set and a loadbalancer (WebApps are hosted on IIS on VMs in Azure).

If I run only on Server and the load balancer send all request to one server every works well, but if I start both server and the load balancer sends the reqeuest to both servers, I got an error.

HTTP ERROR 404

https://mydomain/AppName/signin-oidc

could not be found

So, why could my server not work with this normal OpenId Connect redirect Url?
Should I use a different Middelware to handel the Azure AD /OpenId Connect Authentification?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...

  services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
  ...
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Azure load balancer operates on layer 4. It doesn't maintain cookie based sessions. Azure load balancer uses hash based routing method and hence you are getting 404 as it is routing the authenticated request to a different server.

You can consider using Application Gateway which is a Layer 7 load balancer where you can enable cookie based affinity to maintain your sessions.

Comment: Thanks, I dedected this setting option on the Application Gateway but we use a workaround for our UI. We used a Base-Path on the Application Gateway that points on only on server.